# Java - Iterate + Instantiate Directory of Classes

Tags: java, file, class, object, dynamic

I have a Java class called `Intent`. In a directory called `intents`, I have defined several child classes of `Intent`. Now, in my runner class, I would like to instantiate each of the child classes into an array list as such:

```
public static String parseTranscript(String transcript) {
    ArrayList<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

    File[] intentFiles = new File("./intents").listFiles();
        for (File fileName : intentFiles) {
          //for each of the intents defined in "intents/", 
          //create a new class and add to the array list.

          //intents.add(new fileName.ObjectName()); 
        }
  }
```

So, if I understand correctly, I would need to open the directory, get all file names, then create an object from that file name. What is the best way to do this?

File structure:

```
- Intent.java
- Main.java
- intents/
    - HelloIntent.java
    - GameIntent.java
    .
    .
    .
```

The goal is to do this *without* having to manually define each child class in the runner.

Comment: This depends on what environment you're running in. Most generally as a baseline, I suggest looking at the [SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way. With `Class.forName` and then checking if `getSuperclass` returns `Intent`

```
ArrayList<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
String pathName = "./intents";
File[] intentFiles = new File(pathName).listFiles();
for (File fileName : intentFiles) {
    if (fileName.isFile() && fileName.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
        String className = packageName + '.' + fileName.getName().substring(0, fileName.getName().length() - 6);
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(className);
        if (aClass.getSuperclass().equals(Intent.class)) {
            Constructor<?> firstConstructor = aClass.getConstructors()[0];
            Intent o = (Intent) firstConstructor.newInstance(null);
            intents.add(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting `pathName` would be better do in this way:

```
String pathName = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResources("intents").nextElement().getFile();
```

Getting right constructor maybe need change in this:

```
Constructor<?> firstConstructor = aClass.getConstructors()[0];
```